# MySQL IN() strange behavior

Tags: mysql

If i do a select like this:

```
SELECT `id` FROM `table` WHERE `id` IN (1,2,3)
```

it works but if i do like this:

```
SELECT `id` FROM `table`
WHERE `id` IN (`column`)
```

where column is an internal column with values: 1,2,3  it returns only 1

This is the query:

```
SELECT a.id, (
   SELECT f.name FROM facs f WHERE f.id IN(REPLACE(a.facs, ';', ','))
) AS facs
FROM ads a LIMIT 0, 10
```

Thanks

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing your table structure and some sample data.  Also, in your actual query, you're using a table alias `a` in the column list, but you don't define the alias in the table list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`FIND_IN_SET()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function:

```
SELECT a.id, (
   SELECT f.name
   FROM facs f
   WHERE FIND_IN_SET(f.id, REPLACE(a.facs, ';', ','))
) AS facs
FROM ads LIMIT 0, 10
```

Note: Since this is using a function, indexes cannot be used, you should think about storing the `facs` in multiple rows.

Answer (score 3):

I think instead of

```
SELECT `id` FROM `table`
WHERE `id` IN (`column`)
```

You should do :

```
SELECT `id` FROM `table`
WHERE `id` IN (SELECT `column` FROM `table`)
```

Comment: I think it answers the first part of your question... for the rest, can you give more information as the tables a, ads, facs ?

Comment: that won't work because the column has the values like this: 1;2;3;4 and that's why i had to use the replace function